# Subquery with COUNT (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following table:

```
id   | user | createdAt           | pstatus  
-------------------------------------------------------
287  | Foo  | 2013-08-01 17:19:24 | PLAYING  
286  | Foo  | 2013-08-01 17:18:24 | IDLE  
285  | Foo  | 2013-08-01 17:17:24 | PLAYING  
284  | Foo  | 2013-08-01 17:16:24 | BUFFERING 
283  | Foo  | 2013-08-01 17:15:24 | STOPPED
```

How can I query this table to produce the following result? Essentially, I need to get the total number of different values of pstatus per user, per day.

```
User | logdate    | playCount | idleCount | bufferCount | StopCount
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Foo  | 2013-08-01 |         48|        62 |           0 |         4
Foo  | 2013-08-02 |         25|        22 |           0 |         0
Bar  | 2013-08-02 |         22|        32 |           5 |         4
Bar  | 2013-08-03 |         44|        11 |           1 |         0
Foo  | 2013-08-03 |         32|        03 |           0 |         0
```

I know  I can use DATE(createdAt) to get the date per day instead of a timestamp, but I'm struggling with how essential merge the following into a single query:

```
COUNT(pstatus) AS playCount WHERE pstatus = "PLAYING";
COUNT(pstatus) AS idleCount WHERE pstatus = "IDLE";
COUNT(pstatus) AS bufferCount WHERE pstatus = "BUFFERING";
COUNT(pstatus) AS StopCount WHERE pstatus = "STOPPED";
```

I'm pretty sure it needs to be subquery, but struggling with the syntax!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUM` with a condition this will result in a boolean and will give you the count based on conditions

```
SELECT
DATE(createdAt) logdate,    
SUM(pstatus = "PLAYING") playCount 
,SUM(pstatus = "IDLE") idleCount 
,SUM(pstatus = "BUFFERING") bufferCount 
,SUM(pstatus = "STOPPED") StopCount
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `User`,DATE(`createdAt`)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22f9d/3)

Comment: pstatus is on a second table

Comment: @JustinMitchell i don't see second table in OP's question

Comment: Perfect - this was just what I was looking for. FYI final query looks like 

    `SELECT
    User,
    DATE(createdAt) AS createdAtDate, 
    SUM(pstatus = "PLAYING") AS playCount
    ,SUM(pstatus = "IDLE") AS idleCount
    ,SUM(pstatus = "BUFFERING") AS bufferCount
    ,SUM(pstatus = "STOPPED") AS StopCount
    FROM pings
    GROUP BY User,DAY(createdAt)
    ORDER BY User ASC, CreatedAtDate ASC`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   SELECT 
  SUM(CASE 
         WHEN pstatus = "PLAYING" THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS sumPLAYING,
   SUM(CASE 
         WHEN pstatus = "IDLE" THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS sumIDLE,

   SUM(CASE 
         WHEN pstatus = "BUFFERING" THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS sumBUFFERING,
   SUM(CASE 
         WHEN pstatus = "STOPPED" THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS sumSTOPPED
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```